# Plotting multiple plots - rescaling of axes

Tags: r, plot

I found, that axes were rescaled during multiple plotting using par(new=T) parameter.
An example to demonstrate this:

```
a <- seq(1,10, by = 0.25)
b <- sin(a)
c <- sin(2*a)+1
d <- sin(0.5*a)+2
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)

plot(df$a, df$b, type="l")
par(new=T)
plot(df$a, df$c, type="l", col="blue")
par(new=T)
plot(df$a, df$d, type="l", col="red")
```

This is the result.
[image]

Instead of real scales, I have a transformed curves.
And this is the real result:
[image]

I used parameters `axes=F, xlab="", ylab=""` and did not see this "rescaling".
I find it very dangerous, that it is so easy to transform the data during plotting if you do not control y-limits.

Are there better ways to control y-limits than looking for min and max values in all plotted data to avoid this "rescaling" effect?
I have several quite big files and each of them gives only one line from 10 in one plot and I have several plots on one page to compare my data.

The code for the last "correct" image:

```
plot(df$a, df$b, type="l", ylim=c(-1.5,3.5))
par(new=T)
plot(df$a, df$c, type="l", ylim=c(-1.5,3.5), col="blue", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")
par(new=T)
plot(df$a, df$d, type="l", ylim=c(-1.5,3.5), col="red", axes=F, xlab="", ylab="")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Create an empty plot with enough xlim and ylim to accomodate all data
plot(1, 1, xlim = range(df[,1]), ylim = range(df[,-1]), type = "n", ann = FALSE)

#Draw the three lines
lines(df$a, df$b)
lines(df$a, df$c, col="blue")
lines(df$a, df$d, col="red")
```